# Error in JS-code for integrating enhanced e-commerce through GTM for Magento

Tags: javascript, magento, google-tag-manager

I'm currently working on integrating Google Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce on a Magento webshops through Google Tag Manager.

I'm using the extension and guide from Panalysis: https://www.panalysis.com/resources/tag-manager-plus-user-manual/part-2c-set-gtm-tags

Currently, I'm facing issues with this code:

```
<script>
 (function(){
 function sendOneStepCheckout(obj){
 dataLayer.push({
 event: 'onestepcheckout',
 ecommerce: obj
 });
 }

 function hasClass( elem, clas ) {
 try {
 return (" " + elem.className + " " ).indexOf( " "+clas+" " ) > -1;
 }catch(e){return false}
 }

 function checkActiveStep(){
 var step2=document.getElementById('opc-login');
 if (hasClass(step2, 'active')){ return '2' }
 var step3=document.getElementById('opc-billing');
 if (hasClass(step3, 'active')){ return '3' }
 var step4=document.getElementById('opc-shipping');
 if (hasClass(step4, 'active')){ return '4' }
 var step5=document.getElementById('opc-shipping_method');
 if (hasClass(step5, 'active')){ return '5' }
 var step6=document.getElementById('opc-payment');
 if (hasClass(step6, 'active')){ return '6' }
 var step7=document.getElementById('opc-review');
 if (hasClass(step7, 'active')){ return '7' }
 }

 var currentStep = '2';

 try {
 var ec = {{DL - ecommerce}};
 var cos = ec.checkout.actionField.step;
 if (cos == '1') {
 ec.checkout.actionField.step = '2';
 sendOneStepCheckout(ec);
 }
 if (cos == '2') {
 sendOneStepCheckout(ec);
 }
 function timeout() {
 setTimeout(function () {
 var activeStep = checkActiveStep();
 if (activeStep != currentStep){
 var ec = {{DL - ecommerce}};
 ec.checkout.actionField.step = activeStep;
 sendOneStepCheckout(ec);
 currentStep = activeStep;
 }
 timeout();
 }, 1000);
 }

 timeout();
 } catch(e){console.log(e.message)}
 })();
</script>
```

Google Tag Manager reports that there's an error on line 43, 2nd sign:

"this language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT6 mode or better: block-scoped function declaration. Use --language_in=ECMASCRIPT6 or ECMASCRIPT6_STRICT or higher to enable ES6 features."

I've tried searching for the error message without success.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this? I'm running my head against the wall here..

Best regards,
Christian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting the `<script>` tags, sometimes Google Tag Manager acts up if it is presented with code that isn't strict JS syntax.

Comment: Thanks, Lasse! This worked - no error is displayed when I'm saving.